# primordial gravitational waves

Tags: cosmology, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves

After reading some literatures

1. [Maria Chiara Guzzetti, Nicola Bartolo, Michele Liguori, and Sabino Matarrese. Gravitational
   waves from inflation. arXiv preprint arXiv:1605.01615, 2016.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.01615.pdf)
2. [Andrew R Liddle. An introduction to cosmological inflation. arXiv preprint astroph/
   9901124, 1999.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9901124.pdf)
3. [李虹李明哲蔡一夫张新民, 苏萌. 原初引力波与阿里探测计划. 现代物理知识, 2:002,
   2016.](http://kns.cnki.net/KCMS/detail/detail.aspx?dbcode=CJFQ&dbname=CJFDLAST2016&filename=XDWZ201602002&uid=WEEvREcwSlJHSldRa1FhdkJkcGkyR01QcjM0VmVhc3lEM2Q4bVlENHBXQT0=$9A4hF_YAuvQ5obgVAqNKPCYcEjKensW4ggI8Fm4gTkoUKaID8j8gFw!!&v=MjI3NDFTbmNkTEc0SDlmTXJZOUZab1I4ZVgxTHV4WVM3RGgxVDNxVHJXTTFGckNVUkwyZll1ZHNGeS9nVUwvQlA=)

I still have some questions that I don't understand.

According to cosmic inflationary, we know that **Primordial Gravitational Waves**(PGWs) could be produced in the very early universe. And the appearance of PGWs is the result of the metric's tensor perturbation.

But **Why are there perturbations, such as scalar perturbation and tensor perturbation ?**

We know that tensor-to-scalar ratio $r=\frac{A_T}{A_S}$ is one important quantity. The relation between $r$ and inflaton (the scalar field) $\phi$ is that 
$$
r=\frac{8}{m_{Pl}^2}\left(\frac{\dot \phi}{H}\right)^2
$$

So if we can detect the value of $r$, we can know something about Inflation and PGWs.

The second question is that **how do astronomers measure $r$ through direct way (laser interferometer) or indirect way (CMB polarization)?**

Finally, I don't konw why someone likes to place $h_0^2$ before PGWs' energy density $\Omega_{gw}$, i.e. $\Omega_{hw}h_0^2$, see ([Luuk Wagenaar 2016 *Inflation, quantum fluctuations and gravitational waves*](https://esc.fnwi.uva.nl/thesis/centraal/files/f1994216369.pdf) ).

**What does that $h_0^2$ mean ？**

Comment: Thought I came across a piece of information, perhaps relevant to this question, that might just be useful? Please see [Gravitational-wave sensitivity curves, by C J Moore, et al](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.0740.pdf). Specifically, page 7, eq. 28 which defines Hubble's constant as: $$H_0 = h_{100}\times100kms^{-1}Mpc^{-1}$$ Where $h_{100}$ is _Reduced Hubble's Parameter_. This is apparently used in plotting a graph (page 26) of the product of Energy Density ($\Omega_{GW}$) and Reduced Hubble Parameter squared against the Frequency of Gravitational Waves.